# TinyMCE - can we have one toolbar panel that controls many instances?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, customization, nicedit

I'm thinking of switching from NicEdit to TinyMCE, because the latter has ongoing support and development and appears to have more customizable options.

I was trying it out TinyMCE here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/haaaab

Is it possible to have divs being dynamically created which are assigned to one TinyMCE toolbar that can be used for all of them? I've been looking through the documentation but it isn't clear. The effect I'm looking for is this one:
http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=4

As you can see, different inline elements can be controlled by one NicEdit toolbar.
I've already got a nice page going where divs are dynamically added and deleted and smoothly assigned to NicEdit when they are created. Can TinyMCE support this as well?

Comment: I just found out this thread is similar to my question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959272/multiple-tinymce-editors-but-only-one-toolbar?rq=1][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959272/multiple-tinymce-editors-but-only-one-toolbar?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that by using ur own custom format.

check out this fiddle

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Cbcaab

**EDIT**
Updated FIDDLE

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Cbcaab/1

Comment: Thanks, I checked out your demo! but my emphasis is not only on inline editable elements, but on different elements being editable by the same tinyMCE toolbar. In your example, you have ONE textarea (name=content) being edited by TinyMCE. Can we have two different textareas edited by the same TinyMCE instance?

Comment: Errors in the fiddle "GET http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tinymce/4.2.5/themes/advanced/theme.js " - 404